# Python Count Odd and Even in String of Numbers Using Recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am trying to count all the even and odd numbers in a string of numbers using RECURSION in my Python program but it keeps showing me this error: "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting..." Please, can anyone help me out here?

I tried it in JS it worked perfectly...but not on python. I think I am doing something wrong.

BELOW IS MY CODE:

```
def count_even_odd_recursive(string):
    def helper(helper_input):
        odd = 0
        even = 0
        if len(helper_input) == 0:
            return
        if helper_input[0] % 2 == 0:
            even += 1

        elif helper_input[0] % 2 != 0:
            odd += 1

        helper(helper_input[1::])

        if even > odd:
            return f'There are more even numbers ({even}) that odd.'
        else:
            return f'There are more odd numbers ({odd}) that even.'

    helper(string)
print(count_even_odd_recursive("0987650"))
```

Comment: Usually, a `string` consists of `characters`, not `numbers`. How exactly are you converting a `string` into a `collection of numbers`?

Comment: You need to cast `helper_input[0]` to int. Try putting `int(helper_input[0]) % 2 == 0` as the condition for the `if` statement (and its negation for the `elif` condition).

Comment: Most importantly, `count_even_odd_recursive` returns nothing, so `printing` its result (your last statement) should always print `None`.

Comment: @zr0gravity7 I casted it to int, it's gave me None as output.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan yeah exactly! So how can I solve this?

Comment: return helper(string)

Comment: @SamuelAnumudu casting it to int will solve the thrown error. You can return the result of the helper call at the last line of your function implementation, so `return helper(string)`.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your error:

```
def count_even_odd_recursive(string):
    def helper(helper_input):
        if len(helper_input) == 0:
            return 0, 0
            
        odd, even = helper(helper_input[1:])

        if int(helper_input[0]) % 2 == 0:
            even += 1
        else:
            odd += 1  

        return odd, even
            
    odd, even = helper(string)
    
    if even > odd:
        return f'There are more even numbers ({even}) that odd.'
    else:
        return f'There are more odd numbers ({odd}) or the same as even numbers.'
print(count_even_odd_recursive("0987650"))

# There are more even numbers (4) that odd.
```

I fixed your recursion also, not gonna lie, I had no idea how you intended the recursion to happen there, but this is recursive and it works.

Comment: thank you very much! That solution worked just fine! I actually solved it in Javascript and used the same idea in python but didn't work out. Thanks again, I would love to connect with you if you don't mind.

Comment: @SamuelAnumudu If my solution helped you, I would appretiate if you accepted it :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of problems, the first is that when you're checking whether the digit is even, you're trying to perform modulo operator on a string. You can fix this easily by casting using `int()`.

Secondly, your variables `even` and `odd` are local, and you're not actually passing them into the recursive calls to `helper`. To be honest, I'm not sure why this needs to be recursive, but unfortunately in the code you provided there is no recursion happening. If you want it to be recursive, I've reworked it a bit, also adding in a case where the the even digits are the same count as the odd digits:

```py
def helper(helper_input):
    
    if len(helper_input) == 0:
        return 0
    
    if int(helper_input[0]) % 2 == 0:
        return helper(helper_input[1:]) + 1

    return helper(helper_input[1:]) + 0

def count_even_odd_recursive(string):
    even = 0
    if len(string) == 0:
        return "No input provided"
    else:
        even = helper(string)
        
        if even > len(string) / 2:
            return f'There are more even numbers ({even}) than odd.'
        elif even == len(string) / 2:
            return f'There are more odd numbers ({len(string)-even}) than even.'
        else:
            return "Equal digits odd and even."
    
print(count_even_odd_recursive("0987650"))
```